# grubx64.efi made with grub-mkstandalone fails to start under SecureBoot

Tags: grub2, uefi, secure-boot

Using Ubuntu 20.4 with GRUB2 2.04, Shim 15.7 (I think)

I've been following the Simon Ruderich guide to ["Secure Boot with GRUB 2 and signed Linux images and initrds"](https://ruderich.org/simon/notes/secure-boot-with-grub-and-signed-linux-and-initrd)

When booting with the shimx64.efi I see the "Verification failed: (0x1A) Security Violation" error message.

When booting the grubx64.efi directly I see the "shim_lock protocol not found" error.

If I disable SecureBoot, either from UEFI Firmware Interface (F2 during boot) or by using `mokutil --disable-validation` booting with either EFI works fine.

I've added my PK, KEK and db to the UEFI Firmware and I can see by either removing, adding or attempting to boot other EFI signed with other key that this is working as expected.

I've used MokManager interface to enrol my db cert, as this is what the grubx64.efi and shimx64.efi are signed with.

Yet I cannot get any further...

I'm currently considering building my own shim from https://github.com/rhboot/shim

I'd greatly appreciate new ideas on how to tackle this issue.

The problem I'm trying to avoid is the vulnerability of the unsigned /boot/grub/grub.cfg and initrd

Many Thanks

**edit I love that some "helpful soul" has down voted this post without comment, thanks for that one xx

Answer (score 2):

The solution I've found is to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 as it has GRUB2.06, which has the handy `--disable-shim-lock` feature.

The shim lock disabled grubx64.efi can be booted directly as it is signed by my own db.cert which is installed in the UEFI Firmware. This no longer displays the "shim_lock protocol not found" error.

The standalone GRUB then checks the GPG signed Stage 2 boot files and all is secure from start to finish

Comment: Does this disable the verification chain that grub is supposed to dowhen loading the kernel?